# GUI Builder - GUI's Not Present / Disappeared

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I built a couple of UI's for a Google Spreadsheet using the "Build a user interface" function in the Script Editor yesterday.  Everything was working fine last night but when I opened the Google Spreadsheet I discovered that there are No GUIs present.  I'm just starting to learn how to work with Google Scripts and have a couple of problems.

1. Is there a way to recover the information so I don't have to redo all of the work?
2. Is this a common problem with the GUI builder tool?

Any guidance you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not expected, and if it wasn't temporary than it may be a bug. Please use our [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to report problems like these.